# Will the laravel cache overwrite itself if it fails?

Tags: laravel, caching

I wansn't able to produce an error but i do somethimes get them on my server with my cache command. So i wasn't able to test and see what happens.

If if put something in the cache forever with

```
Cache::put('item', $item );
```

And a day later i try to do the same command. If tthe command fails will i keep my old Cache or will it be overwritten with `null`?

I tried running the command again but i only occasionally get errors on it so i don't know what will happen.

Comment: it depends what fails. Most cases it will keep the previous cache state unless the cache itself is what failed (but if that happens you can expected everything to be wiped from the cache)

Comment: Thanks. Most of the time it is getting data via the google analytics api.